# Statistically difference between Normal Multithreading and Executors with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, statistics

Can anybody suggest me how can can I show Statistically difference between Normal

Multithreading and Executors with multithreading in-terms of as e.g  CPU time,Total thread

user time,memory usage, & so on

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the term "Statistically difference". I believe that you are asking about using of executors and plain thread API and what is the difference among them.

First, executors a based on threads; it is just yet another layer on top of them. No magic. Plain threading API allows you creation and managing of multithreaded applications but requires dealing with gory details of thread synchronization, pooling, transfering data between threads etc.

Executors framework solves some of these problems. You can define thread pool policy, choose queue type according to your needs and just put new tasks to the incoming queue. The thread pool will execute the tasks according to it configuration.

Comment: Statistically difference means if we have normal multithreading program and same program using Excutor with threadpools , if we execute both programs there should be some difference between them , how can I show it statistically as POC(proof of concept)?

Comment: @PravinG You are better off showing it by reading the code and seeing that fundamentally the same key classes are used.  Using stats may show they are the same in one use case on one platform, but what happens if you do something different?  Only reading the code will show you its the same in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what your question is asking something that makes little sense.

Before you can meaningfully talk about the "statistical difference" between things, you have to have some way of quantifying and measuring them.  And before that can happen, you have a clear statement of what you are trying to quantify / measure.

What you are asking satisfies none of these criteria.

---

Assuming that you have a meaningful question ...

At a practical level, the normal way that people try to quantify the effect of something like this (using thread pools versus creating new threads) is to develop a benchmark application with variants corresponding to the two strategies.  Then measure the relative performance.  But this has many problems.

The most fundamental problem that what you are actually measuring is effect of the two strategies for that benchmark, and that benchmark only.  Generalizing from the benchmark to other applications is very difficult.  The problem is that there are "hidden parameters" embedded in the design of any benchmark.  For instance, the number of processors, the number of threads, the length and complexity of the tasks, and so on.  Without having a good intuition as to what the parameters are, it is difficult to design a benchmark to take them into account.  And even if you succeed in figuring out what the hidden parameters are and quantifying their effect, you have the problem that you can't figure out what those parameters will be in a real (more complex) application.  At the end of the day, you'll end up with a model that can't give you quantitative answers for real problems.  (Computing has nothing like Newton's Law of Gravity.)